# How to query for posts with either one or another custom field

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, query

Need help querying for posts with either one or another custom field.

Not sure how to use the 'or' operator here, but something like this the blow -

Have tried these:

```
$wp_query->query('post_type=myposttype&meta_value=X||Y||Z');
$wp_query->query('post_type=myposttype&meta_value=X||meta_value=Y||meta_value=Z');
$wp_query->query('post_type=myposttype&meta_value="X"OR"Y"OR"Z"');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a bit hard to understand, as it seems to query for meta_values of `X,Y,Z,AB,ID,IA`. I hope you can still make sense of the below posted code:

```
// query posts that have on of the custom values for the custom meta key 'my_key' 
// and/or one of the custom meta values for the meta key 'your_key'
$posts = get_posts( array(
     'post_type' => 'my_post_type'
    ,'meta_query' => array(
         array(
             'key' => 'my_key'
            ,'value' => array( 'AB', 'ID', 'IA' )
            ,'compare' => 'IN'
         )
        ,array(
             'key' => 'your_key'
            ,'value' => array( 'AB', 'ID', 'IA' )
            ,'compare' => 'IN'
     )
) );
```

Other comparison values would be `'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN'` where the later twos are reserved for numeric comparison and need an extra meta key/value pair: `'type' => 'numeric'`.